# Gerador de senha python

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gerador de senhas em Python, mas quando gera uma senha e aparece a pergunta se o usuário deseja gerar uma nova senha ou não (S/N) mesmo colocando "N" ou "n", ele ainda gera uma última senha nova e dá `break` no loop.

Mas eu queria que quando colocasse não, encerrasse imediatamente.
Aqui o código:

```
print('=' * 20 + '\033[91m Bem vindo ao gerador de senhas personalizado \033[0m' + '=' * 20)

import random
import string

def gerar_senha(tamanho):
    caracteres = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.digits + "!@#?" * 2
    senha = ''.join(random.choice(caracteres) for _ in range(tamanho))
    return senha

tamanho_senha = int(input("Digite a quantidade de caracteres que deseja: "))
senha_gerada = gerar_senha(tamanho_senha)
print("A senha gerada é:", senha_gerada)

refazer = True

while refazer:
   while True:
        opcao = input("Deseja refazer a senha? (S/N): ")
        if opcao.lower() == 's':
            tamanho_senha = int(input("Digite a quantidade de caracteres que deseja: "))
            senha_gerada = gerar_senha(tamanho_senha)
            print("A senha gerada é:", senha_gerada)
        elif opcao.lower() == 'n':
            break
```

Comment: O problema é que vc colocou um `while` dentro do outro, e o `break` só interrompe o `while` mais interno. Uma opção seria [fazer assim](https://ideone.com/aGC8MW). E vale lembrar que a própria [documentação do módulo `random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) diz claramente que este não deve ser usado para fins de segurança e criptografia, e sugere o uso do [módulo `secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) (disponível a partir do Python 3.6).

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

No caso não precisa de dois loops para fazer o que precisa.E para sair do loop while nem sempre precisa de um break segue exemplo:

```
import random
import string

def gerar_senha(tamanho):
    caracteres = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.digits + "!@#?" * 2
    senha = ''.join(random.choice(caracteres)
                     for _ in range(tamanho))
    return senha

refazer = True
while refazer:
    tamanho_senha = int(input("Digite a quantidade de caracteres que deseja: "))
    print("A senha gerada é:", gerar_senha(tamanho_senha))
    opcao = input("Deseja refazer a senha? (S/N): ")
    if opcao.lower() == 'n':
        refazer = False
```

Comment: Um detalhe é que se digitar qualquer coisa diferente de "N", como "abc", "$#@$W#", ou até mesmo nada (só dá um ENTER), o loop continua. Pra um exercício talvez seja preciosismo verificar isso, mas enfim, acho que pelo menos o "S" deveria verificar... E eu pessoalmente prefiro um `break` em vez de criar uma variável de controle só pra isso, mas claro, vai da preferência de cada um

Comment: @hkotsubo  Concordo com o detalhe da verificação se for diferente de "N". Mas resolve isso  mudando a verificação para opcao.lower() != 'n':. Mas isso fica a criterio de quem fez a pergunta. Em relação a variavel de controle. Quiz demostrar que nem sempre é necessário o uso de break. Mas como ele iniciou uma variavel, eu somente quiz demostrar uma alternativa ao break